# How to set tv banner for my app when installed on firestick?

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv

Tv banner is not showing on firestick. when I install my app on tv emulator it's showing tv banner image on home screen. but when installed same apk on firestick it's showing regular launcher icon instead tv banner. I've added `android:banner` properly on manifest.

Comment: This question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58962060/how-to-set-the-fire-tv-icon-on-home-screen