# How to set the Fire TV "icon" on home screen?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback, amazon-fire-tv

I have a Fire TV app that will also be released on normal Android TV and one some TVs that have Android that isn't Android TV and possibly on tablets. So I've set my banner for Android TV and that is working fine, the icon works fine on other devices but the Fire TV shows the icon where I expect the banner to be shown. This is my application xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:banner="@drawable/banner"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".start.MainActivity"
        android:banner="@drawable/banner"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/banner"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What am I missing? I make the custom xml as well with what's below but didn't help:

```
<resources>
    <drawable name="splash_logo">@drawable/banner</drawable>
    <drawable name="app_logo">@drawable/banner</drawable>
    <drawable name="company_logo">@drawable/banner</drawable>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer my own question, that appears to come from the Amazon App Store. Once I released my app, the banner magically changed on its own.

Answer (score 0):

If it is accepted, yes—but if not then you must have something like:

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   ...
```

Please note that this `ic_launcher` must be 192x192.

Comment: Does that work for apps that are not released on the App Store? Basically sideloaded apks?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are saying it only works on newer Fire TV OS versions?